# Mass import of keymappings from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, keymapping

My organization just switched from using Eclipse to using Android Studio. There are things I like about both, but I'm more familiar with Eclipse. I'm wondering if there is a way to mass import keyboard mappings that I set up in Eclipse to Android Studio.

Most of my keyboard mappings in Eclipse are standard (insert the usual line about just learning the keymap for Android Studio, but I'm lazy), but there are a few I've customized.

Basically, I'm wondering if there is a script that can do this for me that I just don't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your key bindings to Eclipse key bindings by going to File > Settings and clicking on Keymap. Then select Eclipse (or anything else you want). From there, you can add the few you've customized.

Edit: Not aware of a mass import.